# wpdb : select from custom table : sql error

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm getting an error while trying to query a custom table using the wpdb class. Here is my code :

```
global $wpdb;
$dates_bloquees = $wpdb->query( 
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT datesbloquees FROM $wpdb->datesbloquees WHERE idproduit = '%d' ", $postid ) );
```

Error message :

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE idproduit = '1'' at line 1]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help,

François

Comment: You can try storing `prepare` value in an array and output it too see what's wrong with the SQL syntax.

Comment: You want to get data from you custom table ?